# Purpose of Synthesize

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using an iOS5 book to learn iOS programming.

```
@synthesize coolWord;
```

^synthesize is used for all properties in .m files

I heard that in iOS6 there is no need for synthesize, since it is automatically done for you. Is this true?

Does synthesize play any role for iOS6?

Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: This is not a property of iOS 6.  It is a property of Xcode 4.4.  Take a look at the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html).  This is the “Default synthesis of `@property` instance variables and accessor methods” feature.

Comment: Even though it's a just a property of Xcode, I assume you can still do this for iOS6 apps though, right?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

@synthesize in objective-c just implements property setters and getters:

```
- (void)setCoolWord:(NSString *)coolWord {
     _coolWord = coolWord;
}

- (NSString *)coolWord {
    return _coolWord;
}
```

It is true with Xcode 4 that this is implemented for you (iOS6 requires Xcode 4). Technically it implements `@synthesize coolWord = _coolWord` (`_coolWord` is the instance variable and `coolWord` is the property).

To access these properties use `self.coolWord` both for setting `self.coolWord = @"YEAH!";` and getting `NSLog(@"%@", self.coolWord);`

Also note, both the setter and getter can still be manually implemented. If you implement BOTH the setter and getter though you NEED to also manually include `@synthesize coolWord = _coolWord;` (no idea why this is).

Comment: Thank you! You explained the synthesize concept and its role in iOS6 very well. :)

Comment: The code that is actually generated is a bit more complicated and depends on how the property is defined and if you have implemented some or all of the generated methods yourself. For example if you have a atomic property (which is the default) then the generated setter will make sure that only one thread can modify the underlying variable at any time. There are dozens of other factors that influence the code that is generated. The fact that you don't have to worry about those things anymore (in most cases) is nice. ;)

Comment: Still can not understand synthesize, @Christian Kienle.

Comment: If I have one variable testString inside interfaqce {} block. And same property testString. I have to write synthesize. To tell the OS that both this variable are same. Why ? still I do not understand what is _ funda.

Answer (score 9):

Autosynthesis in iOS6 still requires `@synthesize`

- to generate accessor methods for properties defined in a `@protocol`.
- to generate a backing variable when you included your own accessors.

---

The second case can be verified like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface User : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger edad;
@end
@implementation User
@end
```

Type: `clang -rewrite-objc main.m` and check that the variable is generated. Now add accessors:

```
@implementation User
-(void)setEdad:(NSInteger)nuevaEdad {}
-(NSInteger)edad { return 0;}
@end
```

Type: `clang -rewrite-objc main.m` and check that the variable is NOT generated. So in order to use the backing variable from the accessors, you need to include the `@synthesize`.

It may be related to [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-autosynthesis-of-properties):

> Clang provides support for autosynthesis of declared properties. Using
>   this feature, clang provides default synthesis of those properties not
>   declared @dynamic and not having user provided backing getter and
>   setter methods.

Comment: Thats not true. You can also generate the ivar yourself: `@implementation MyClass { NSInteger _edad; } /* getter & setter here */ @end`

Comment: I was referring to autosynthesis. I edited the answer for clarification.

Comment: @Jana "to generate accessor methods for properties defined in a @protocol". Protocol is just a contract, how does the compiler know what setter and getter to generate? By looking at the contract ?

Comment: Using `clang -rewrite-objc main.m` just gives me an enormous main.cpp file. Is there something I need to include to make it output Objective-C?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how `@synthesize` relates to iOS6 but since Xcode 4.0, it's essentially been deprecated. Basically, you don't need it! Just use the `@property` declaration and behind the scenes, the compiler generates it for you.

Here's an example:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

/*Code generated in background, doesn't actually appear in your application*/
@synthesize name = _name;

- (NSString*)name
{
    return _name;
}

- (void) setName:(NSString*)name
{
    _name = name;
}
```

All that code is taken care of the complier for you. So if you have an applications that have `@synthesize`, it's time to do some cleanup.

You can view my similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658737/using-synthesize-in-ios-application/14658879#14658879) which might help to clarify.

Comment: Yay Xcode! This will probably save me at least 5 minutes everytime I create a new class. :)

Comment: Good explanation. Here have a cookie in the form of an upvote.

Comment: Good explanation, @barndog. Generally we do not write setters and getters. So, we assign this work to compiler, by writing synthesize. That's what you want to tell.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `@synthesize` directives are automatically inserted in the latest Obj-C compiler (the one that comes with iOS 6).

The point of @synthesize pre-iOS 6 is to automatically create getters & setters for instance variables so that `[classInstance getCoolWord]` and `[classInstance setCoolWord:(NSString *)aCoolWord]` are generated.  Because they are declared with `@property`, you also get the convenience of dot syntax for the getter and setter.

Comment: "you also get the convenience of dot syntax for the getter and setter." can you explain this in  more detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
hope this will help little more

yes previously we have to synthesis the property by using @synthesis now it done by IDE itself.
```

but we can use it like

// what IDE does internally

```
@synthesis name=_name;
```

we use _name to access particular property but now you want synthesis by some other way like
firstname  you can do it like

```
@synthesis name= firstname
```

or just by name

```
@synthesis name=name
```

Answer (score 0):

With automatic synthesis in iOS6, it is no longer necessary to specifically declare backing ivars or write the @synthesize statement. When the compiler finds a @property statement, it will do both on our behalf using the guidelines we’ve just reviewed. So all we need to do is declare a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *abc;
```

and in iOS 6, @synthesize abc = _abc, will be added automatically at compile time.

Comment: Note that as @Joel says, this isn't always true.

Comment: synthesise will be added automatically ? is not true. OR abc=_abc the naming is not always true ? @Inafziger.