# Using @synthesize in ios Application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was watching the wonderful Paul Haggerty in the iTunesU courses for iOS development (cause who doesn't need to refresh on the basics?) and he said something that I wasn't aware of:

> "We will never access underbar ( the _ symbol) variables"

He then went on to talk about how when you use @property to declare your variables,`@synthesize variable = _variable` is code that's generated behind the scenes by the complier, as well as the setter and getter. Essentially that code never should appear in your app.

In all of my iOS apps I've written thus far, I always declare my variables using `@property` in my header file and `@synthesize VARIABLE_NAME = _VARIABLE_NAME;` Since watching the lecture, I'm now confused as to if I should be using `@synthesize` in my code at all.

Should I just use the property declaration? What difference does it make, if any, if I use the synthesize declaration in my code?

Since Mr. Haggerty doesn't use it, then why do I? (considering he's sort of an iOS demi-god). I very much feel like it's bad form to do what I've been doing.

Anyone care to clarify that issue?

Comment: Backing variable synthesis is automatic, and therefore, @synthesize has effectively been deprecated.  Really, you would only need it to declare a backing iVar with a different name than the auto-synth'd one (which is a terrible practice anyways). Remove em' all, and clean up your variable access.  Nothing should change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically @synthesized properties in Xcode 4.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666008/automatically-synthesized-properties-in-xcode-4-4)

Comment: @CodaFi, what is backing variable ?

Comment: An `@property` declaration generates a set of accessors (getter [and setter assuming the property is not `readonly`]) and automatically allots itself storage in the instance with an implicit iVar declaration.  When I speak of backing variables, I'm talking about that iVar.

Comment: ivar means instance variable ?  that we declare insede interface block ?

Comment: i think yes,as marked answer says correctly as what you say.

Comment: @CodaFi, Now there is no need to write “synthesize” in your code , but only if you have instance variable (Inside interface block) and property variable, you have to write synthesize.
Still do not understand _ funda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Xcode 4.0 Developer Preview 4 Release Notes.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW105) Adds default automatic synthesis of properties (iOS and 64-bit OS X). You don’t need the `@synthesize` directive in the implementation sections for the compiler to synthesize accessors for declared properties.

So

```
@synthesize ivar = _ivar;
```

is exactly same if you omit it.

Comment: Well that's awesome. Really good to know that. Upvote if you want ;)

Comment: @shadow sorry for some wrong info just checked the release notes and found it was present since 4.0. Hope you check these notes :) (edited my answer)

Comment: Ok awesome! Yeah I was wondering what the deal with because all the code I look at, things on github and whatnot, all use the synthesize declaration. Apple really needs to be more open about what they change and not just at WWDC :P

Comment: There is no difference they are just saving our time. And sometimes (most of the times with me) it happens that I forgot to write `@synthesize` and it's good for me that compiler generate it for me :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer any need for synthesize. This was also covered in a WWDC session this year. Just use properties.

Answer (score 2):

Not including "@synthesize VARIABLE_NAME = _VARIABLE_NAME" will do the exact same thing as if you actually included it, since the compiler will automatically add that if you don't add anything.

Answer (score 2):

with Xcode 4.5 or up. The IDE write the `@synthesize` statement for you.

The `@synthesize` statement is only write the `setter` and `getter` for you.

that, `_variable_name` is the instant variable.

The `variable_name` is only a method that returns the value of `_variable_name` by default.

when using the `variable = <Statement or value>. its calling the`setVarable_Name`method to set the`_variable_name` by default.

Hope it helped.