# Setting read only property a value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a read only property

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly)  NSInteger   keepalive;
```

With a getter method

```
-(NSInteger)keepalive
{
    return _keepalive / 1000;
}
```

**ERROR - Use of undeclared identifier**

And trying to set a value in `init` method

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _keepalive = 25000;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**ERROR - Use of undeclared identifier**

Couldn't understand the reason why and what's the right way to have a readonly property, with a getter.

EDIT:
I wouldn't want to add `synthesize` as suggested in the comment, since it's not needed anymore - [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658849/978133) AND I got the correct answer below.
Thank you André Slotta!

Comment: @originaluser2 - I disagree with your 'duplicated' marking. Please read my editing. Thanks

Comment: @Josh Caswell- I disagree with your 'duplicated' marking. Please read my editing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case you could redeclare the property as readwrite in your implementation file:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly)  NSInteger keepalive;
```

.m:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite)  NSInteger keepalive;
```

This lets you use compiler-generated atomic setters and getters inside of your implementation, but not expose the setters to the rest of the world.

(see https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/property-values/)