# Is @synthesize required in the xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have a property like window
I saw in some example use:

```
@synthesize window = _window
```

is this statement still necessary for xcode5 and above?

Comment: No, that is deprecated. @property takes care of everything you need.

Comment: This should answer your question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658142/ios6-purpose-of-synthesize. In short, not needed, it's auto synthesized since Xcode 4.

Comment: @niksawtschuk It's not deprecated.

Comment: FYI - The version of Xcode is irrelevant. Whether you need `@synthesize` or not is a function of the compiler, not the IDE.

Comment: @nhgrif my apologies, that was the first word to come to mind and it wasn't exactly what I meant to say. Leaving my comment as a lesson for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`@synthesize` is no longer *necessary* for properties.

Properties are auto-synthesized to their name prefixed with an underscore as of Xcode 4.

HOWEVER, `@synthesize` is **NOT** deprecated.  If you don't like the underscore convention, you can manually synthesize your properties to whatever you want.

Additionally, properties declared in `@protocol`s are **NOT** auto-synthesized, but can still be synthesized using the `@synthesize` keyword.